# Appending unique values in a singly linked list in java

Tags: java, linked-list

I want to append into a linked list without duplication of values. This is my function: But this does not filter out duplicates. Any idea where I am going wrong? Node consists a string value and a next pointer.

```
public static void append( Node head, Node newNode ) {  
   Node currentNode = head;  
   while( currentNode.next != null ) { 
      if(currentNode.value.trim().equals(newNode.value.trim())) {
         return;
      }
      currentNode = currentNode.next;
   }  
   currentNode.next = newNode; 
}
```

Comment: Could you post a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 4):

You're not checking the final node for duplication (as jtahlborn said in his answer, which was deleted when I started writing this one...). You need to keep going until `currentNode` is null, but you *also* need to remember the previous node so you can use it as the tail node.

Here's a short but complete program showing it working. It's got nasty package-access fields etc, but it works...

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node head = new Node("head");
        append(head, new Node("foo"));
        append(head, new Node("bar"));
        append(head, new Node("bar"));
        append(head, new Node("bar"));
        append(head, new Node("baz"));
        dump(head);
    }        

    public static void append(Node head, Node newNode) {
        Node currentNode = head;
        Node previousNode = null;

        while (currentNode != null) {
            previousNode = currentNode;
            if (currentNode.value.trim().equals(newNode.value.trim())) {
                return;
            }
            currentNode = currentNode.next;
        } 

        previousNode.next = newNode;        
    }

    public static void dump(Node head) {
        Node currentNode = head;

        while (currentNode != null) {
            System.out.println(currentNode.value);
            currentNode = currentNode.next;
        } 
    }
}

class Node {
    String value;
    Node next;

    Node(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: This maybe a sill question but why not just add in the end to the current = newNode?

Comment: @dreamcrash: Why would you expect that to help? Changing the value of the local variable `currentNode` wouldn't change the `next` node of the tail...

Comment: @dreamcrash: No, because just changing the value of `currentNode` will have no effect. If you meant why didn't I use `currentNode.next = newNode`, *that's* because it will be null.

Comment: Thanks, for the explanation, I am more accustomed to linked list in c using recursion.

Comment: I was think that since currentNode = head; the currentNode was pointing to the same memory address of the original linked list. So changing currentNode would also be notice in head.

Comment: @dreamcrash: Stop thinking in C. Java isn't C. Changing the value of `currentNode` would have *no effect*. (I'd have to see the C version to agree or disagree with you about the C version, too...)

Answer (score 1):

you never check the last node for duplication.

best way to find problems like this in the future is to step through your code in a debugger, not ask questions on a forum.  otherwise, you will never learn to code on your own.